# Why wont my villagers breed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing on a 1.16.4 single player world. I've been working on getting some OP villagers and I need to get two different enchanted books. I'm breeding them because the village was left with only two villagers. I'm doing it again since my fifth villager didn't become a zombie villager when I tried to turn him to one so I can get the good discounts. I've bred my other three a few times, once with one pair and twice with one from the other pair and my third one. I tried this time twice with the second pair and then tried with the pair I haven't before but it didn't work. I just thought to try with my fourth villager and another one. It didn't work and the clouds appeared above their heads. I was confused because I thought that you got the cloud effect because of the same pair of villagers have been bred too much together, which is why I tried with different pairs. I tried again after giving them potatoes again but the clouds happened again. Is it because one is a librarian and an unemployed villager? I'm very sure that I've set it up correctly but I could be wrong, so that's why I've come here. I really need this so I can get better armor to fight the Ender Dragon. The picture is the set up, not very complicated but it has worked so I'm pretty sure it works.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the [wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Villager#Breeding) on how it all works? At the moment you haven't got much information on how exactly your set up is going. The main thing you'll need to accommodate for is the number of beds, or move the bred villagers away from the beds used for breeding

Comment: This same set up has worked well. I give them both 12 potatoes then put them together. I place a bed and it normally works. The room is 4 blocks tall which should be fine. I've read the wiki about the breeding and willingness and I'm pretty sure its all fine, but I'll look over it again

Comment: Each *new* villager requires their *own* bed. That's the main change. If you have the same number of villagers and beds, they will not breed, as there are no free beds to fill.

Comment: I'll try again with more beds, just a bit confused why that would be the issue if it's worked before placing only one to three beds with three or four villagers.

Comment: Just an update, it did work, thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud effect appears when there are no free beds for the child to occupy. There must be a pathfindable (not necessarily reachable; caveats like trapdoors etc apply) bed not assigned to any other villager within reach from the point the two villagers attempt breeding.

The mechanics of bed assignment are slightly buggy; sometimes a bed remains assigned even though the villager is no longer among us. I'd suggest breaking and replacing all the beds, and possibly if you don't have some clever breeding setup, just placing lots of beds within reach.